# GAMS, How to save the standard output to a file in linux shell?

Tags: linux, save, gams-math

I am wondering how can I save the standard output of a GAMS running process in a file? The .lst file is very big and I just need the solution process.

Answer (score 0):

You may split the .lst using retroves or magrit softwares.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem. GAMS writes output to the screen in a fashion that cannot be redirected using `>` or `2>&1`. But in unix, you can save the output to file using:

```
$ gams file.gams LogOption=2
```

You can read more here:

https://www.gams.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fgams.doc%2Fuserguides%2Fmccarl%2Flogoption_lo.htm

Answer (score -1):

You should add a `> filename` at the end of your command-line.

Something like

```
#> ./my-process > filename.res
```

This will only redirect standard output. Standard error will still be displayed in the terminal window.